# What's the __fields__ does in python?

Tags: python

I recently came across with a python snippet that would create a different object model. Part of that code countians `__slots__` with `__fields__`.

```
class Reptor(object):
    __slots__ = __fields__ = 'type', 'code', 'deviated_angle'
```

`__slots__` would creates tuple object instead of dictionary object which minimize the object size and add the immutability to it. But I can't understand what's `__fields__` part in here?

And `__fields__` has been used in `__repr__`

```
def __repr__(self):
    fields = ', '.join(repr(getattr(self, f)) for f in self.__fields__)
    return f'(type(self).__name__)({fields})'
```

Comment: `__fields__` is not special cased by Python. It is just a name. Some other part of a framework may expect to find it, but that is impossible to tell from your information.

Comment: I think Mister is correct, but it's not an unreasonable question to ask

Comment: So what's basically means is it an alias that added to use when it's necessary. Thanks

Comment: @GovindaMalavipathirana most probably, but the answer could probably be elaborated upon if you could provide us with context and what's the framework was used with this snippet

Comment: @Rightleg I have updated the question. It seems `__fields__` has been used as an name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
__slots__ = __fields__ = 'type', 'code', 'deviated_angle'
```

`__fields__` is also set here. This is basically shorthand for:

```
__fields__ = 'type', 'code', 'deviated_angle'
__slots__ = __fields__
```

`__fields__` has no special meaning in Python, so it's probably used by other parts of your application.

Comment: Incorrect, `__slots__` is special just not `__fields__` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472000/usage-of-slots